# Is the meaning of "travel company", "travel firm" and "travel agency" the same?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

I wonder whether the meaning of "travel company", "travel firm" and "travel agency" is the same. Can we use them interchangeably to vary the language in a paragraph?

Comment: I’m most familiar with the term travel agent or travel agency (e.g the Carnival Cruise). I don’t often hear travel firm/company in conversations.

Answer (score 2):

While Radu Miron's answer isn't incorrect per se, in a general context, the terms in your example **are** entirely interchangeable.  You could also add "travel bureau", or "travel organisation" if you need more.

However, if your paragraph is discussing or explaining different types of companies that assist travellers (assuming there is a range of types of travel company), then you would need to be careful about which company type you used where. It all depends on the context.

Incidentally, as inferred by Radu Miron, travel agency is probably the most precise of the choices as they act as an intermediary between clients.  You could also use "travel agent"/"travel agents" without loss of clarity - even though this would, strictly speaking, refer to a person/people rather than a company.

Comment: +1 for _bureau_ and for _agent_. At least in the U.S., the use of the term _agent_ in place of _agency_ or _company_ seems to be quite pervasive. I'm more likely to say, "I need to call a travel _agent_" than _agency_, even when I have no idea about the name of the person who might pick up the phone. About the only time I'd be inclined to use _travel agency_ over _travel agent_ is when I'm referring to the company building, as opposed to the workers inside, as in, "I need to stop by the travel agency on my way home tonight."

Comment: This is true. They could all be used interchangeably but not in the same paragraph. Wasn't this the question here?

Comment: To vary the language? Yes they could, why not?  You wouldn't want to go overboard and try to use *all* of them, but within reason, any and all of a subset of the alternatives could be used.

Comment: @mcalex: That's another way to look at it. You'd only need to avoid varying up the terms if you thought it might confuse the reader.

Answer (score 0):

*Company*, *firm* and *agency* have their own particularities. A ***firm*** is an partnership or association for carrying on a business. An ***agency*** is a particular kind of ***company*** which serves as an intermediary between clients. Using them interchangeably in the same paragraph could be confusing.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "interchangeably." If I'm talking to a coworker, and I say, "Excuse me for a moment, I need to call my travel agency," I could probably substitute _firm_ or _company_ without confusing anyone. However, if I was writing a book about travel to Europe, I'd probably want to be consistent, and not refer to an _agency_ in one chapter, and a _firm_ in another.